# If the conditions warrant

Tags: intransitive-verbs

### !

[Source](http://online.wsj.com/article/SB10000872396390443864204577623220212805132.html)

> 'Central bank securities purchases have provided meaningful support to the economic recovery,' he said adding later that, 'we should not rule out the further use of such policies if economic conditions ***warrant***.'

The verb ***warrant*** is transitive.  So is a ***it*** or ***that*** missing after ***warrant***?

Comment: To my ear *it* is required.

Comment: To my ear, _it_ is not required.  So I guess it's a regional difference.

Comment: @DavidWallace So, an INTRANSITIVE version of the verb ***warrant*** exists?

Comment: No, I believe it can only be transitive.  But here, the object is implied - it's "the further use of such policies", even though the same phrase is the object of another verb.  In my speech, I would omit a duplicated object like this one, and I probably wouldn't even provide a pronoun.  I don't know whether this is a regional anomaly or not.

Comment: Without a technical explanation (so it's not really enough for an answer), I'd be fine with hearing "warrant" without "it", but in reading it, there's the feeling of ending too abruptly.

Comment: This user is [currently suspended](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/23135/nortonn-s), and as usual, the question has been [lifted from another site](http://www.englishforums.com/English/IfConditionsWarrant/bcbzlg/post.htm)

Comment: @DavidWallace My mistake in responding. I should have said that to my ear, *it* sounds preferable to *that*, not that *it* is necessarily required.

Answer (score 5):

*Warrant* is transitive, but in this case the object *it* is missing. This is an example of *ellipsis*. ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_%28linguistics%29#Noun_ellipsis))

Answer (score 0):

Yes, *warrant* is transitive, but more to the point is whether it's a good choice of verb at all. What the speaker presumably meant was  *if economic conditions **justify** it* (*or them*).

Comment: So, "if economics conditions warrant" is wrong and it should rewritten as "if economic conditions warrant ***IT***" ?

Comment: I think the particular construction itself might be forgiven in speech, but something like 'justify' still seems to me to be a more appropriate word in the context.

Comment: So, I could write ***"if the conditions require"*** instead of ***"if the conditions require IT"***?

Comment: It makes no difference. 'Require' is also a transitive verb. It is possible to omit 'it' by way of ellipsis, but in formal writing it would be advisable to include it.

Comment: Interesting! I'm in the group that likes they way this phrase sounds as is. To me the *it* is implied and understood.  I also think *require* could be used with or without *it*.  *Justify* seems to require *it* and seems a little out of place here because it implies strength of the economy to support (finance) such an action rather than weakness of the economy necessitating the action.  Just my opinion here, but I find the nuances of words very interesting. Glad for others perspectives!

Comment: [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/warrant#Verb) lists "justify" as a synonym for "warrant".  It was a perfectly cromulent usage to my ear.

Answer (score -1):

> 'Central bank securities purchases have provided meaningful support to the economic recovery,' he said adding later that, 'we should not rule out the further use of such policies if economic conditions **warrant**.'

..

I am confused by the use of nouns or verbs in this context.  I wonder if you could explain?

..

> Warrant is transitive, but in this case the object it is missing. This is an example of ellipsis.

..

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ellipsis

> The omission of a grammatically required word or phrase that can be inferred.

..

---

So in this case we have the omission of 'it' which is not very helpful, because you always have to think what 'it' is and sometimes 'it' is nothing.

> 'Central bank securities purchases have provided meaningful support to the economic recovery,' he said adding later that, 'we should not rule out the further use of such policies if economic conditions **warrant it**.'

---

So what is 'it'?

> 'Central bank securities purchases have provided meaningful support to the economic recovery,' he said adding later that, 'we should not rule out the further use of such policies if economic conditions **warrant central bank securities purchases**.'

Comment: That is the definition of 'warrant' as a noun. It's a verb in the OP's example.

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I think that I was struggling with the status of warrant as a verb or noun.  Perhaps it similar to 'to prove' and 'proof'.  I tried to use the word 'prove'because it was in the definition whereas justify has much more natural feel.

Comment: Right, but answers are for answering the question.  Comments are for commenting on the question, or requesting further information about what was actually meant.  The intention of every Stack Exchange site is to provide expert answers to useful questions.  If you don't understand the question, then answering it may be considered unhelpful.